# tsoa swagger docs for express RequestHandler endpoints

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsoa

Here is a controller endpoint code for which I'm trying to make use of `tsoa` for the generation of swagger documentation. `tsoa` works for endpoints' class methods with simple query/path parameters, however, this approach is pretty different.

In the `controller.ts` file, there are no class methods but `RequestHandler`s.

```
const createValidationChain = [
    body('name').notEmpty().withMessage(errorMessages.required('name')),
    body('description').optional(),
    body('subcategories')
        .custom((subcategories) => Array.isArray(subcategories))
        .optional()
];

const createCategoryHandler: RequestHandler<
    CreateCategoryParams,
    ResponseOrError<CreateCategoryResponse>,
    CreateCategoryRequest
> = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let getCategoryByName;
        if (req.body.name) {
            getCategoryByName = await CategoryModel.findOne({
                name: req.body.name
            }).exec()
        }
        if (getCategoryByName) {
            return res.status(StatusCodes.CONFLICT).send({
                fieldErrors: [{
                    field: "name",
                    message: `Category with name '${req.body.name}' already exists!`
                }
                ]
            })
        }
        const newCategory = await CategoryModel.create(req.body);
        return res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).send(newCategory);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.sendStatus(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
};
export const createCategory = [
    validateMiddleware(createValidationChain),
    createCategoryHandler,
];
```

The `CategoryModel` = model('Category', categorySchema); is just a simple schema with a few properties.

```
export const categorySchema = new Schema<Category>({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    description: { type: String },
    subcategories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubCategory' }]
}, {
    timestamps: true
}
)
```

Next, I have a router that is finally injected into the express app.

```
import express, { Router } from 'express';
import * as controller from './controller';
const router: Router = express.Router();
...
router.post('/', controller.createCategory);
...
export default router;
```

I'm trying to find a way how to 'easily' auto-generate swagger documentation for the endpoints. I've seen the options here [tsoa docs](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/introduction.html) but can't catch something useful for my endpoints.
Any suggestions or recommendations?

Or, someone to recommend other than `tsoa` packages that could help with this case?